# Is it permissible to wear body protection material or gear under the clothing when keeping wickets in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, equipment, baseball

Can you wear baseball keepers' protective gear under your clothing in cricket?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange! I really didn't get you clearly. Can you please give more information on what exactly do you asking?

Comment: An image of that material would help us understanding this post..

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes it is allowed to wear baseball protective gear for cricket.

You are discussing about the protective gears under the clothes in baseball, ie, specifically about the leg-pads.

[image]

It looks more or less same as the cricket leg-pads.

[image]

Only the wicket-keeper and the fielders in short leg and silly point [are allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cricket_and_baseball#Fielding) to use the leg-pads in cricket, but the leg-pads used by Wicket Keepers in cricket is slightly big and goofy than baseball leg-pads. Since the cricket ball is more hard than baseball. So, that type of pads are preferred  by cricketers. No rules were block them to wear baseball leg-pads.

We can see some of the cricketers [using baseball helmets](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/426986.html) [in cricket](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/6202647.stm).

[image]

Comment: you have mentioned only wicket keepers can use the leg pads but even fielders who field at short leg use the pads. Are they allowed to use it?

Comment: @suhas, yes the fielders in short leg can wear pads, but those shin pads look very small and wore inside the pants. The legpads worn by Wk is different from Fielders.

Comment: @suhas, edited the answer. And one more thing, the question is specifically about WKs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed,but after Umpire's consent (according to the law). But under the clothing, I don't think so. Helmets were allowed in a few cases (Dinesh Karthik, McGlashan).

Fielders at forward short leg or any other fielding postion closest to the pitch often wear shin guards(non-cricket gear/generic sports gear).

While, other fielders use a thick layer of bandages/tapes on fingers.

**[Law 40- Wicket Keeper](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-40-the-wicket-keeper/)**

**[Law 41- Fielder](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/)**